# Rows not being returned in stored proc

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two rows in dbo.Members but my stored proc is not returning a count. I can run the query alone like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Members WHERE MemberID = 1234` and it returns the count as 2 which is correct.

Why does it not return the rows in my stored proc?

```
SELECT
    ValidCount,
    InvalidCount,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Members WHERE MemberID = @pMemberID) AS 'TotalMembers'

FROM
    dbo.Reporting
WHERE
    MemberID = @pMemberID
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because you don't have entries in `Reporting` with `MemberId = 1234`.

Try this:

```
SELECT  COALESCE(validCount, 0) AS validCount,
        COALESCE(invalidCount, 0) AS invalidCount,
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    members m
        WHERE   m.memberId = p.memberId
        ) AS totalMembers
FROM    (
        SELECT  @pMemberId AS memberId
        ) p
LEFT JOIN
        reporting r
ON      r.memberId = p.memberId
```

Comment: what's the **p** for `FROM(SELECT @pMemberId AS memberId) p`

Comment: Ok great this works. Is there a way to make the Invalid & Valid columns return 0 instead of NULL?

Comment: @Quassnoi great, so it will only show 0 if it returns null. otherwise, it will return it's actual value, correct?